# Excel VBA Copy and Paste Loop under last used row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Complete beginner to Excel VBA here. I have a list of people on column "A" and want to copy and paste cell "B2", not related to the list of people, onto another column, eg column "D", as many times as there are people on the list. However, I want this list of copy and pastes of cell "B2" to start on a specific row, eg "D10", and when I run the code a second time, the list will be carried on below it.

My current code can copy and paste into the new column as I want to, but it does not paste as many times as there are people on the original list.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub copyloop()
Dim i As Integer
Dim NoOfCrew As Long

NoOfCrew = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 9)
NoOfCrew = NoOfCrew + 1

For i = 1 To NoOfCrew
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & NoOfCrew).PasteSpecial
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Surely you want `Min` not `Max` ?

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to require one var for # of crew and another for the starting position.

```
Sub copyloop()

    Dim NoOfCrew As Long, StartAt as long

    with workSheets("Sheet3")

        NoOfCrew = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        StartAt = application.Max(NoOfCrew , 10, _
                                  .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)

        .Range("D" & StartAt ).resize(NoOfCrew, 1) = .Range("B2")

    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess my sample data was different from yours.